# Why do we need Auto-encoder? How is it useful in real life implementation?

Tags: neural-networks, python, dimensionality-reduction, unsupervised-learning, autoencoders

From what I've learned about autoencoder is it takes an input and predicts an output almost similar to the input. So, if it outputs the same thing with the same dimensions, what is the benefit of using autoencoder then? We can directly work with the inputs.

Comment: three terms are you answer: Unsupervised Representation Learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that an auto-encoder outputs the same dimension as the input, but it goes through a smaller hidden layer.  Imagine a series of layers, from input to output, each with the following number of neurons:

1000 : 500 : 100 : 500 : 1000

The 1000-dimensional input is squeezed through a 100-dimensional middle layer.  Once trained, if you remove the last two layers, and only use:

1000 : 500 : 100

the 100-dimensional middle is a reduced dimensional representation, pure an encoding.  You could use that as input to another learning method - another neural network or something else.

Think of it like PCA in which you only use the first few PCs.  Principal components regression works in this way, but uses a linear projection of the data to lower dimensions, whereas the auto-encoder uses a non-linear protection.

Comment: Thanks, got it.

Comment: Is it useful only for the training data? I mean if we take the 100-dimensional middle of an instance outside training would the latent representation be good enough? The decoder didn't see this instance during training so we can say that the latent representation would be good but the decoding part (when reconstructing it) would be bad?

Comment: If the new instance came from the same distribution(s) as the original data, it should be fine.  Conceptually, using an auto-encoder would be similar to normalizing the training data and then using the means and standard deviations from that to normalize the test data.  You would not want to retrain it on the test data.